# Get error "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguos" when creating a new field

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new field `newfield` according to values of the field `field1`. If its value belongs to a list `mylist1`, then `newfield` should be equal to `111`. If its value belongs to a list `mylist2`, then `newfield` is equal to `222`.

```
mylist1 = ["A","B","C"]
mylist2 = ["D","E","F"]
df.loc[df["field1"] in mylist1,"newfield"] = "111"
df.loc[df["field1"] in mylist2,"newfield"] = "222"
```

This code works if I use, for example, `df["field1"]=="A"`. However it fails with lists. How to solve this issue?

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: need `df.loc[df["field1"].isin(mylist1),"newfield"] = "111"`

Comment: [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html)

Comment: I comment only, because duplicates.

Comment: @jezrael: Thanks. Could you please explain why doesn't it work with `in`? I guess that `in` is a correct way to work with lists.

Comment: Yes, check [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#using-the-in-operator)

Comment: `in` works with scalar values (single values), here you're comparing an array, which will return an array of boolean values which it doesn't understand and it's ambiguous how to treat these hence the error

Comment: @EdChum: Ok, thanks.